# HLSL print function while run the code for unity shader compute

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, compute-shader

i use `HLSL` for shaders in unity games and i need to print some **values** and the `HLSL` dont have **console** or something like console ,because it is run from unity compute shaders.

so How i can print the Values in HLSL.

Comment: You can't actually *print* from shaders, but you can definitly use debuggers.

Comment: _"so How i can print the Values in HLSL"_ - quite simply _**you can't**_.  Remember a shader runs for all pixels at the best of times so even if you could your console would fill up pretty quick.    Generally people make a funky shader to diagnose shaders where particular colours imply certain states about the shader.

Comment: Also, the CPU doesn't have access to the internals of the GPU and this is especially the case for compute shaders (GPGPU) due to their love for all things massively parallel.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-VertexFragmentShaderExamples.html.  examples there how you can use a shader to output debug _colours_. See _"Using mesh normals for fun and profit"_

Answer (score 0):

Use RenderDoc to debug shaders.

https://renderdoc.org/

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderDocIntegration.html